# Как скомпилировать код python 3.10 код в exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exe, python-3.10

Я создал программу на Python 3.10.0rc. И хотел скомпилировать её в exe файл. В программе был использован match-case (новая языковая конструкция, доступная в версии 3.10). Если я использую `python имя_файла`, всё работает как должно. Но если компилирую через pyinstaller, то получается Syntax Error.

Ошибка :

```
Syntax error in D:\binarian\compiler.py
  File "D:\binarian\compiler.py", line 21
     match lexic[0]:
           ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Если вам так уж принципиально скомпилировать, то перепишите на более старые конструкции, видимо, pyinstaller ещё не приспособлен к 3.10, да и вообще как-то странно тянуть release candidate в продакшен или куда там, на нём хорошо экспериментировать, конечно, но не в дело его сразу пускать )

Comment: Так я и экспериментировал, это проект написанный за 5 часов. И я просто хочу залить на гитхаб exe и рядом с ним исходники.

Comment: exe переоценен. есть прилестные конструкции вроде pyz, плюс виндовый энтрипоинт и портабл версия питона - не "один файл" но зато без компиляции

Comment: Проверьте, что pyinstaller у вас запускается именно через python 3.10, а не более ранней версии.

Answer (score 1):

Тут скорее ошибка в том что пайинсталер запущен из окружения старого питона.

Pyinstaller не компилирует `py` файлы в exe, он запускает встроенный в питон компилятор в `pyc` и пакует их в самораспаковывающийся архив.

Установите Pyinstaller в новый Питон.

АП. https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5693 ждем пока закроют, а пока работоспособность в 3.10 не гарантированна..

Comment: Я указал абсолютный путь к файлу из нужной папки и получил ImportError: No module named _bootlocale

Comment: к какому файлу, из какой папки?

Comment: "D:\python310\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" В папку python310 я установил python.

Comment: pyinstaller как ставил?

Comment: pip3.10 install pyinstaller

Comment: пакет упакован как универсальный, но поддержка python3.10 похоже не готова. это уже вторая проблема)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129122/discussion-between-farkon00-and-eri).

Comment: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5693 почитай обсуждение и жди новой версии